# Convert a string to list

Tags: racket

Calling all racket developers, I am a newbie  in the language of racket. I want to convert a string to a list.

I have a string like this:

```
"(1 2 3 4 5)"
```

I want to converted to:

```
'(1 2 3 4 5)
```

I tried using string-> list but this is the result:

```
(#\(
  #\1
  #\space
  #\2
  #\space
  #\3
  #\space
  #\4
  #\space
  #\5
  #\))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible way, using Racket's `read`.

```
#lang racket

(define (convert str)
  (with-input-from-string str
    read))

(convert "(1 2 3 4 5)") ;=> '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Normally, `(read)` will read an input from standard input. However, I use `with-input-from-string` to redirect the read operation on a string instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here we split the string while ignoring the non-digits, then convert the digits to numbers:

```
#lang racket

(define (convert str)
  (map string->number (string-split str #px"[ )()]")))

(convert "(1 2 3 4 5)")

; => '(1 2 3 4 5)
```